# How to make all the balls move until they stop by NBodySimulation

Tags: differential-equations, simulation, singularity, event-detection, discontinuity

```
n = 4;
countTime = 5;
SeedRandom[5];
initPos = RandomPoint[Disk[], n];
data = NBodySimulation[
   Association["PairwisePotential" -> "Coulomb", "Region" -> Disk[], 
    "ExternalForce" -> (Quantity[-0.5 Normalize[
          QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]](*An extra damping*), "Newtons"] &)], <|
      "Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], 
      "Position" -> Quantity[#, "Meters"], 
      "Velocity" -> Quantity[{0, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"], 
      "Charge" -> Quantity[10^-5, "Coulombs"]|> & /@ initPos, 
   countTime];
colors = RandomColor[n];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Riffle[colors, Point /@ data[All, "Position", time]]}, 
  Axes -> True], {time, $MachineEpsilon, countTime, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

[image]

I noticed that because one of the balls is coming to rest, the other balls can no longer be simulated because the iteration spacing is 0 after `t>4.09486`. How can I solve this problem so that the simulation continues until all the balls are at rest?

I guess we can change certain system options by `Block`? But I don't know which system option is causing this error...

Comment: You can control the method of integration for the underlying ``NDSolve`` by providing the option ``Method``. Because the systems are Hamiltonian, the default choice in ``NBodySimulation`` is ``"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta"``. You can try with ``Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`` which goes past the stiffness point, but soon after that, unfortunately, the balls wander outside the circle ... Internally, reflections from the walls are performed via ``WhenEvent``s. Perhaps there is already an answer here at MMA.SE on how to properly set up ``WhenEvent``s for such cases ...

Comment: @Domen I note the method of  `ExplicitMidpoint` ,`StiffnessSwitching` and `Extrapolation` all will avoid error  result the  balls wander outside the circle. I don't know if this is a bug or not in `NBodySimulation`

Comment: @yode What force do you try to describe with  option `"ExternalForce" -> (Quantity[-0.5 Normalize[
          QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]](*An extra damping*), "Newtons"] &)`?

Comment: @AlexTrounev If I don't add damping to the charge,  those charges will never stop. This force I am describing is like friction, always in the opposite direction to the speed and constant in magnitude.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution 1

Funny, I'm not sure if this is the only solution, but `Method -> "ExplicitEuler"` (we know this is a rather primary method for ODE solving) solves the problem. This seems to be the first time I found a problem can be resolved with `ExplicitEuler`!

I've also added `StartingStepSize -> 10^-3` to speed up the calculation a bit. (The default step choosing is around `10^-6`, which turns out to be unnecessarily small. ) The calculation takes about `6` seconds on my laptop, tested in *v12.3.1*.

Result:

[image]

```
ListPlot[#, PlotRange -> All] & /@ data[All, "Position"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

### Solution 2

Not as straightforward and efficient as **Solution 1**, but a possible work-around is to define a smoother `Normalize`:

```
norm = Compile[{{v, _Real, 1}}, 
  If[v == {0, 0}, {0., 0.}, 2/Pi ArcTan[10^4 Total[v^2]] v/Sqrt@Total[v^2]], 
  RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False]
```

Use `norm` instead of `Normalize` in the code produces a solution visually the same as that of **Solution 1**, it takes about `26` seconds on my laptop, though.

---

### Remark

I attempted to spot the root of problem, without success. But `NBodySimulation` has probably set up the system properly, because even if the problem is set up with `NDSolve` and `WhenEvent` manually, the issue remains.

The following is the code. Definition of `data` is the same as that of OP, definition of `reflect` is taken from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263596/1871), `showStatus` is from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/134793/1871):

```
reflect[vector_, normal_] = -(vector - 2 (vector - Projection[vector, normal]));

f[x_, y_] = x^2 + y^2 - 1;

eq = data["Equations"] /. {Subscript[\[FormalQ], i_] :> Subscript[x, i], 
    Subscript[\[FormalP], i_] :> Subscript[x, i]', \[FormalT] -> t};

event = WhenEvent[
     f @@ #[t] == 
      0, {#'[t] -> 
       reflect[#'[t], {Derivative[1, 0][f] @@ #[t], 
         Derivative[0, 1][f] @@ #[t]}]}] & /@ (Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[4]);

var = (Subscript[x, #] & /@ Range[4])[t] // Through;

init = <|"Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], "Position" -> Quantity[#, "Meters"], 
     "Velocity" -> Quantity[{0, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"], 
     "Charge" -> Quantity[10^-5, "Coulombs"]|> & /@ initPos;  
ic = {var == Through@init["Position"], 
      D[var, t] == Through@init["Velocity"]} /. t -> 0;

showStatus[status_]:=LinkWrite[$ParentLink,
  SetNotebookStatusLine[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],
                     ToString[status]]];
clearStatus[]:=showStatus[""];
clearStatus[]
jianshi[t_]:=EvaluationMonitor:>showStatus["t = "<>ToString[CForm[t]]]

sol = NDSolveValue[{eq, event, ic} /. 
      HoldPattern@Quantity[a__] :> QuantityMagnitude@Quantity@a /. 
     QuantityMagnitude -> Identity, Head /@ var, {t, 0, countTime}, jianshi[t], 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity(*, Method -> "ExplicitEuler", 
    StartingStepSize -> 10^-3*)]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

`NDSolveValue` stops at `t==4.09`, too.

Comment: I note a built-in function ``NDSolve`NBodySimulationDump`reflect`` is equal to your `-reflect[vector, normal]`. but what is `jianshi[t]` in your code?

Comment: @yode Oops, it's something in my tool bag. Code added.

Comment: BTW, that is a good name. :) And do you think this is a bug about `NDSolveValue` as your analyze?

Comment: @yode Glad you like it. :D Not necessarily a bug, but at least a performance issue, I think. Something might be wrong with the adaptive step choosing of default ODE solver, but of course this is no more than a guess of mine. I suggest you reporting this to WRI.

Answer (score 6):

If we put `countTime = 20` and remove `Normalize` then we have desired rest state

```
n = 4;
countTime = 20;
SeedRandom[5];
initPos = RandomPoint[Disk[], n];
data = NBodySimulation[
   Association["PairwisePotential" -> "Coulomb", "Region" -> Disk[], 
    "ExternalForce" -> (Quantity[-0.5 QuantityMagnitude[#[
           "Velocity"]](*An extra damping*), "Newtons"] &)], <|
      "Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], 
      "Position" -> Quantity[#, "Meters"], 
      "Velocity" -> Quantity[{0, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"], 
      "Charge" -> Quantity[10^-5, "Coulombs"]|> & /@ initPos, 
   countTime];
colors = RandomColor[n];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Riffle[colors, Point /@ data[All, "Position", time]]}, 
  Axes -> True], {time, $MachineEpsilon, countTime, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We also can regularized force proposed by yode as follows

```
n = 4;
countTime = 8;
SeedRandom[5];
initPos = RandomPoint[Disk[], n];
data = NBodySimulation[
   Association["PairwisePotential" -> "Coulomb", "Region" -> Disk[], 
    "ExternalForce" -> (Quantity[-.5 (1 - 
           Exp[-10 Norm[QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]]]) Normalize[
          QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]](*An extra damping*), 
        "Newtons"] &)], <|"Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], 
      "Position" -> Quantity[#, "Meters"], 
      "Velocity" -> Quantity[{1. 10^-12, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"], 
      "Charge" -> Quantity[10^-5, "Coulombs"]|> & /@ initPos, 
   countTime];
colors = RandomColor[n];
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{Circle[], Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Riffle[colors, Point /@ data[All, "Position", time]]}, 
  Axes -> True], {time, $MachineEpsilon, countTime, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Hi, if we remove `Normalize` that means that the faster the ball is, the more damped it is, which is probably not a physical reality.  The damping should be velocity independent.

Comment: @yode Actually damping is velocity dependent, for instance, in the water or air the friction force is proportional to $-k\vec{v}$ at small v and $-k_1|v|\vec{v}$ at large v.

Comment: Well, I mean in a disc that ignores air resistance as this post. :)

Comment: @yode  Do you try to describe dry friction with some minimal velocity to start?

Comment: Yes. And thinks for your solution. :)

Comment: @yode I see, that for this specific unphysical force $−0.5\vec{v} /v$ there is unphysical result. :) But with regularized force  $−0.5(1-e^{10 v})\vec{v} /v$ we have desired rest state - see update to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of your external force:

```
(Quantity[
    -0.5 Normalize[QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]](*An extra damping*)
, "Newtons"] &)
```

blowing up at small velocity, because of the normalizing factor going infinity $$\hat{v}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{v\cdot v}}\right)v\;,\quad \lim_{v\to\vec{0}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{v\cdot v}}=\infty\;.$$
To avoid this, you could define the external force as a piecewise function:

```
(Piecewise[{
    {Quantity[-0.5 Normalize[QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]], "Newtons"], Norm[QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]] > 10^-1},
    {0, Norm[QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]] <= 10^-1}
}] &)
```

As a side note, specifying the units and mapping the quantities to their magnitude is not very necessary but has a significant performance impact. Compare, for example, with this:

```
n = 4;
countTime = 5;
SeedRandom[5];
initPos = SetPrecision[RandomPoint[Disk[], n], 10];
data = NBodySimulation[
    Association[
        "PairwisePotential" -> "Coulomb",
        "Region" -> Disk[],
        "ExternalForce" -> (Piecewise[{
            {-0.5 Normalize[#["Velocity"]], Norm[#["Velocity"]] > 10^-1},
            {0, Norm[#["Velocity"]] <= 10^-1}
        }] &)
    ],
    Association[
        "Mass" -> 1,
        "Position" -> #,
        "Velocity" -> {0, 0},
        "Charge" -> 10^-5
    ]& /@ initPos
, countTime];
colors = RandomColor[n];
Manipulate[
    Graphics[
        {Circle[], Red, PointSize[0.02], Riffle[colors, Point /@ data[All, "Position", time]]}
    , Axes -> True]
, {time, $MachineEpsilon, countTime, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

---

**Addendum.** This is an explicit explanation as to why the `Normalize` part blows up in `NDSolve`. User @xzczd insists otherwise, further claiming that `Normalize` doesn't transform into anything, such as `x/Abs[x]`. While that's partially true, it's only when the input is already given as a number. When `NDSolve` computes a step, it first turns the terms containing variables/target function in the equation into their effective numerical form as much as possible, such as `Normalize[{x'[t],y'[t]}]` to `{x'[t]/Norm[{x'[t],y'[t]}],y'[t]/Norm[{x'[t],y'[t]}]}` and then to `{x'[t]/Sqrt[Abs[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2]],y'[t]/Sqrt[Abs[x'[t]^2+y'[t]^2]]}`. One can easily check this:

```
Trace[NDSolve[{Normalize[{f[t], 0}] == {f'[t], 0}, f[0] == 1}, f, {t, 0, 1}]][[1, 1, 1]]

(* {Normalize[{f[t], 0}], {f[t]/Abs[f[t]], 0}} *)
```

Now, in the case of damping, if `"Velocity"` or numerical `f'[t]` gets small at some sufficiently large step (sufficient enough to kill off the precision) during `NDSolve`, then it's straightforward `f'[t]/Abs[f'[t]]` blows up:

```
q1 = 1`10;
q2 = 1`10 + 1/5*10^-9;
dq = q2 - q1;

Precision /@ {q1, q2, dq}
(* {10., 10., 0.} *)

dq/Norm[dq]
(* Error encountered; Indeterminate *)
```

One workaround is to define the function (damper) piecewise, for small `Norm`. This is precisely what I did above, which effectively solved the problem.

Comment: The solution works, but the explanation isn't quite right, actually `Normalize[{0, 0}]` evaluates to `{0, 0}`.

Comment: @xzczd Not quite. `0` is specially returning `0`. Otherwise `Normalize[x]` is equivalent to `x/Abs[x]`.

Comment: That's what I meant. There's no blow up.

Comment: @xzczd `Normalize[...]` never jumps to `0` when `...` is a floating number. You're suggesting that `Normalize[{0,0}]={0,0}` but this doesn't have much point because `{0,0}` has infinite precision, whereas `NDSolve` handles floating numbers. A better argument would have been suggesting `Normalize[{0., 0.}]={0.,0.}`, but when `NBodySimulation` gets a result having overshooting precision (i.e., higher than the working precision), it returns `singularity or stiff system suspected` or, in other words, blowing up.

Comment: But you claimed that "This is because of your external force blowing up". The reason why `ndsz` warning pops up in this case isn't immediatly clear, but I'm pretty sure it's not caused by blowing up of external force. Also, observing the solution up to `t==4.09` suggests the solution doesn't blow up, either. (`ndsz` warning doesn't necessarily mean there's a blow-up, see e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219656/1871 , you can find more by searching `ndsz` in this site. )

Comment: @xzczd I'm sorry, but I don't see much reason to continue this conversation when you're not supporting your claim with reasons other than "it just doesn't blow up". I can't seem to find much useful info in the link you provided either. Try this: `s=NDSolve[{q''[t] == -1/Abs[q'[t]], q[0] == 0, q'[0] == 0.1}, q, {t, 0, 1}]` which is a simplified version, which, of course, also blows up (`Plot[q[x] /. s, {x, 0.0045, 0.0050}, PlotRange -> All]`). Mind you, `Normalize[x]` is equal to `x/Abs[x]` for floating `x`.

Comment: As mentioned at beginning, the only thing I want to say is, your explanation is wrong. `Normalize[x]` never blow up, `x/Abs[x]` cannot be simplified to `1/Abs[x]`. As long as `x` is a non-zero vector, `Normalize` always manages to normalize `x`. Try e.g. `Normalize[{10^-100., 10^-100.}]`.

Comment: @xzczd Okay, I see where you're missing now. That argument is not quite relevant in `NDSolve` for couple of reasons. As I mentioned, `NDSolve` carries over every (floating) number with its working precision. When it handles `Normalize[q']`, it's doing `q'/Norm[q']`. If `q'` has piled up precision from many iterations of `NDSolve` at some step, then `q'/Norm[q']` blows up because `Norm[q']` becomes effectively `0.` due to working precision having lower precision. This is why `NDSolve` returns ndsz.

Comment: "When it handles `Normalize[q']`, it's doing `q'/Norm[q']`." Why do you think so? `Normalize` is never transformed to anything else, this can be easily proved by checking the `NDSolve\`StateData[…]` object. Try `sd = First@First@Flatten@Trace[NBodySimulation[……], _NDSolve\`StateData]; sd["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]` Also, the `ndsz` warning can be circumvented by setting another ODE solver, see my answer.

Comment: "When `NDSolve` computes a step, it first turns the terms containing variables/target function in the equation into their effective numerical form as much as possible, such as `Normalize[{x'[t],y'[t]}]`" But this doesn't happen in OP's case because `NBodySimulation` internally defines **implicit** vectors, just like in e.g. `Trace[NDSolveValue[{Normalize[f[t]] == f'[t], f[0] == {1, 1}}, f, {t, 0, 1}]]`. Once again, please check the `NDSolve\`StateData[…]` carefully.

Comment: Another way to prove `ndsz` is not related to "blow up of `Normalize`" is to define `Normalize` as a black-box which will never be expanded for symbolic vectors: `normalize[a : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := Normalize[a]` The `ndsz` warning still pops up at `t=4.09` with `normalize` instead of `Normalize` in OP's code.

Comment: @xzczd I don't think I deserve a negative vote from someone who's not willing to be a little more critical other than constantly insisting/giving vague arguments. Firstly, what `StateData` are you referring to? Also, what do you mean by implicit vectors? Lastly, of course it blows up again, as you effectively defined a tautological statement - try doing `normalize[{q, q}] /. q -> 1`, and piecewise define your `normalize` and see if it still works (it does).

Comment: 1. `sd = First@First@
   Flatten@Trace[
     NBodySimulation[
      Association["PairwisePotential" -> "Coulomb", "Region" -> Disk[], 
       "ExternalForce" -> (Quantity[-0.5 Normalize[
             QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]](*An extra damping*), "Newtons"] &)], <|
         "Mass" -> Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], "Position" -> Quantity[#, "Meters"], 
         "Velocity" -> Quantity[{0, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"], 
         "Charge" -> Quantity[10^-5, "Coulombs"]|> & /@ initPos, 
      countTime], _NDSolve\`StateData]; sd["NumericalFunction"]["FunctionExpression"]`

Comment: @xzczd I'm sorry, but your syntax doesn't seem to be correct - `sd` is empty and so it shows only errors. Edit: now it works.

Comment: 2. By implicit vector I mean something like `f[t]` in `NDSolveValue[{Normalize[f[t]] == f'[t], f[0] == {1, 1}}, f, {t, 0, 1}]`, `f[t]` is not expressed as a explicit list `{…}` in the code, but it's undoubtedly a vector. 3. "try doing `normalize[{q, q}] /. q -> 1`…"So what? Can you make it expand to something involving `Norm[{q, q}]`?

Comment: @xzczd What is your idea about `Normalize` after all? The way it produces the output? Do you think some wizards zaps and voila, the output pops up? I can't seem to find how it's designed, but most likely just compiled version of `x/Abs[x]` with special value `0` at `x=0` or `0.` for numeric zero. If we assume that, then it appears to be that `NDSolve` make `Normalize` completely forget about the precision of its input, because `Normalize` in `NDSolve` never seems to give `0.` in any step. I'll try to update my answer about this or even post question if I have time later.

Comment: "…`Normalize` in `NDSolve` never seems to give `0.` in any step" I don't think so, try the following: `normalize[a : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := Sow@Normalize@a; {data, {veclst}} =Reap[NBodySimulation[Association["PairwisePotential"->"Coulomb", "Region" -> Disk[],"ExternalForce"->(Quantity[-0.5*normalize[QuantityMagnitude[#1["Velocity"]]], "Newtons"] & )], (Association["Mass" ->Quantity[1, "Kilograms"], "Position" -> Quantity[#1, "Meters"], "Velocity" -> Quantity[{0, 0}, "Meters"/"Seconds"],"Charge" -> Quantity[1/10^5, "Coulombs"]] & ) /@ initPos, countTime]];Cases[veclst, a_ /; a == {0, 0}]`

Comment: @xzczd They are the initial velocities... Change the initial velocities to something else and check again.

Comment: OK, so you mean steps other than initial steps, then it's the case. But I don't think this is because "`NDSolve` make `Normalize` completely forget about the precision of its input", because if you define `normalize[a : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}] := Normalize@Sow@a;` and check e.g. `{tst = Cases[veclst, a_ /; Norm@a <= 0.13 10^-7], Normalize /@ tst}`, you'll see the inputs are never close enough to `{0,0}`. This might be because `NDSolve` has failed to choose a proper step size around `t=4.09`, but this is no more than a guess. (I'm not sure why `ndsz` pops up in this case, as said above. )

Comment: @xzczd You're still not getting it. Or are you just insisting? If it's former, it will never get 'close' to `0.` because the external force or `Normalize` blows up and `ndsz` happens. This is why I suspect `NDSolve` makes `Normalize` forget  about numeric-zeros-input. It's not hard for you to see that now, just check how minimum norm in the list changes as you increase `WorkingPrecision`. `Norm` reaches the precision limit, `Normalize` wants to blow up, `ndsz` happens. There is no other reason. Also, if you're worried about stepsize, why don't you just alter `MaxStepSize`? ;)

Comment: But with `Sow` we've monitored all the inputed velocities (with `Normalize@Sow@a`, notice in my last comment I've moved `Sow` **into** `Normalize`) and normalized velocities (with `Sow@Normalize@a`), if there exists blow-up, where is it? Why isn't it catched by `Sow` and `Reap`? Also, notice the velocities of 1st and 4th particle are already very close to `{0,0}` around `t=4.09`. (Just plot it. ) As to `MaxStepSize`, this option can only be used to avoid steps that's too large AFAIK, but in this case `NDSolve` has already chosen a rather small step, I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: @xzczd You can never catch singularity with `Sow` and `Reap` from `NDSolve` because when `NDSolve` has a step yielding singularity, it stops and puts out error. Trying to catch singularity is unnecessary to begin with, because `NDSolve` knows better; putting out at where it has singularity (in this case, $t\approx4.09$). Regarding velocities approaching numeric zero, that is precisely why `Normalize` or `z/Abs[z]` blows up. You keep refusing to accept that, but could you ever explain why `NDSolve` puts out singularity? And why does limiting `Normalize` to non-small norms fix the issue?

Comment: I'm not talking about singularity, I'm talking about the blow-up you keeps talking about. As I've said for several times, I don't know why `NDSolve` spit out `ndsz`, in many cases the reason is just unclear (I showed one example above, which you seems to fail to understand. BTW here's another: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/189770/1871 ), but I'm sure it's not caused by blow-up of `Normalize`, because `Sow`/`Reap` has catched every calculated velocity. (Or you think `NDSolve` can *predict* blow-up with some magic power? )

Comment: @xzczd That first sentence doesn't make any sense to me, as blow up happens due to singularity, and singularity causes blow up... lol  Well, I see that I can't do anything for you at this point, sorry.

Comment: "And why does limiting `Normalize` to non-small norms fix the issue? " If I have to guess, it's because this essentially makes `Normalize` less steep, because the original `Normalize` **jumps** from `{vx,vy}` (`vx^2+vy^2==1`) to `{0,0}`. My **Solution 2** and Alex's update follows the same spirit. But this doesn't explain why setting `ExplicitEuler` as the ODE solver resolves the problem as shown in my **Solution 1**.

Comment: @xzczd `Normalize` never jumps to `{0.,0.}` (not `{0,0}`) from anything. You couldn't capture that from `Sow` and `Reap` either... Alex's solution hasn't touched `Normalize`, which I find odd that you mentioned (or am I missing something?). And to be fair, what you did in your second solution is simply changing the precision that `Normalize` handles in a cheapy way. One can reproduce the same result in a more clever way by multiplying some big number up and down to `x/Abs[x]`.

Comment: "Normalize never jumps to {0.,0.}… You couldn't get capture that from `Sow` and `Reap`" If I understand your words correctly, yes, that's another reason to  refuse the assumption. As to Alex's solution, notice Alex added the term `Exp[-10 Norm[QuantityMagnitude[#["Velocity"]]]])`, this term essentially links the non-zero region to `{0,0}` with a smooth function. "what you did in your second solution is simply changing the precision…“ I don't think precision is related. ”You can reproduce the same … by multiplying some big number up and down to `x/Abs[x]`" Please prove it with specific code.

Comment: Aha, I see another possible explanation. **Solution 2** etc. do make `Normalize` smoother in another sense. Suppose there's a vector `{x,x}` where `x` varies from `-1` to `1`, compare the folllowing: `Plot[First@Normalize@{x, x}, {x, -1, 1}]` `Plot[First@If[-10^-1 < x < 10^-1, {0, 0}, Normalize@{x, x}], {x, -1, 1}]` `Plot[First@norm@{x, x}, {x, -1, 1}]` `Plot[First[(1 - Exp[-10 Norm@{x, x}]) Normalize@{x, x}], {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]`. But still, this doesn't explain why `ExplicitEuler` works.